# Chrome Console Error: chromeHidden.Port.dispatchOnDisconnect

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome, protocols, port

NO idea what that means. Been developing some facebook apps and some apparently related js errors show up.

According to this thread it's a lazy load issue. I am running chrome with the default settings though.
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=100977

Once and a while (about one in five times) this breaks facebook app authentication. chromeHidden.Port.dispatchOnDisconnect shows up like 8 times sequentially in the console, with no indicator of what code is breaking.

Anyone else encounter this, or know exactly what causes it? Is it javascript bugs from facebooks? Some sort of protocol error? Port mismatch?

Comment: **'Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to generally relate to programming or software development in some way, within the scope defined in the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).'**  Voted to move to superuser.com where you will have a better chance of getting technical support.

Comment: I have this problem aswell with an app that i'm developing on for facebook.

Comment: @KristofferNolgren added a bounty to keep it interesting. Can you post your steps to reproduce? the FB app I was working on no longer produces this, but I don't know what caused it.

Comment: I saw a bug-report on chromium regarding a flag called lazy-loading, I have never activate that though. It's only my account that suffers this problem. I run the following plugins: AdBlock 2.5.37, BrowserTexting 1.35, Chat for Google 1.2012.606.2, Collusion for Chrome 1.5.6, FlashBlock 0.9.31, RSS Subscription Extension (by Google) 2.2.0, Safebit 0.312, Show Password on Focus 1.0.1. I also have th flags: Enable syncing open tabs, Enable Panels, Enable auto-login and Enable Chrome To Mobile.

Comment: Do you encounter the same issue in incognito modus (ctrl+shift+n), as in that mode at least all extensions should be disabled (+some other stuff)?

Comment: Doing my own research on this issue I've seem to come across a lot of people with a similar issue of it not happening 100% of the time. A common relationship between many users that do have it happens to be they keep Chrome open for quite some time instead of closing it when they are done. Some of these people seem to have it open for days and open and close many tabs as well as having their computer go into a few sleep sessions. I'm not sure if that is relavent to you or not. What version are you running?

Comment: goes on/off when I enable/disable "Google Chrome to Phone Extension"

Comment: Very odd. Well, it all seems to be related to extensions or conditions within chrome, and not anything in the code of the actual site or my app.

Comment: I also have this status message on about every page and I am using Chrome to Phone too. Can we blame this extension?

Comment: I recently encountered issues with the same error when Chrome updated. I had to disable an out-of-date extension.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you've disabled an extension and the problem no longer persists, please file a bug against the extension (probably most pertinent) or the Chromium forum (http://code.google.com/p/chromium/).

Comment: here it is: http://code.google.com/p/chrometophone/issues/detail?id=316&q=chromeHidden.Port.dispatchOnDisconnect

Comment: I had not installed any extra extensions at that point, and now seems that chrome cleans out unintended extension installations. This was so long ago I can't even remember which facebook app i was developing.

Answer (score 12):

Mine was due to the chrome2phone extension